# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): appUser is not iterable

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the response from my rest api to a React state.  I tried to do this like I read in this SO post: [useState object set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451029/usestate-object-set)

Here's what I tried:

Admin.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Button} from "../components/AuthForms"
import {useAuth} from "../context/auth";
import axios from 'axios';

function Admin(props) {

    ...

    const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
    const [appUser, setAppUser] = useState({pk:-1, username: '', email: '', first_name: '', last_name:''});
    const key = !authTokens ? "Logged out" : authTokens.key;


    if (!!authTokens) {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            console.log('Admin() response is ', response);
            setUsername(response.data.username);
            setAppUser(...appUser, response.data); <==== here's where I get the error.
        });

    ...

    // display the logged in user info.
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Admin Page</div>
            <div>Key: {key}</div>
            <div>Username: {username}</div>
            <div>App User pk: {appUser.pk} username: {appUser.username}</div>
            <Button onClick={logOut}>Log out</Button>
        </div>);
}

export default Admin;
```

How should be setting appUser?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the object braces:

```
 setAppUser({...appUser, ...response.data})
```

Also put it in a `useEffect` to only fetch the data if `authTokens` changes:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (authTokens) {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            console.log('Admin() response is ', response);
            setUsername(response.data.username);
            setAppUser({...appUser, response.data}); <==== here's where I get the error.
        });
}, [authTokens]); // The [authTokens] means, that it will only fetch the data again if authTokens changes
```

Also why do you do `!!authTokens`? You can remove the `!!`.

Comment: Doing `setAppUser({...appUser, response.data});` gives me `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`.  The `!!` is from some other developer.

Comment: And doing `setAppUser({...appUser}, response.data);` seems to have caused an infinite loop.

Comment: Is it caused by the same line? Are you sure you have typed it correctly? I edited the post further with a simple optimization.

Comment: Does `setAppUser({...appUser, ...response.data});` work? I updated my post.

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. I do get a warning ` Line 43:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'appUser'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setAppUser(a => ...)' if you only need 'appUser' in th
e 'setAppUser'`

Comment: I disabled that warning since sometimes you just don't need those dependencies.