# Change Default Sort and Order for React Jhipster

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I am using Jhipster 6.8.0 and trying to change default sorting (sort by : publishedDate and order : desc) based on the following code:

```
const [paginationState, setPaginationState] = useState(getSortState(props.location, ITEMS_PER_PAGE));

  const getAllEntities = () => {
    if (search) {
      props.getSearchEntities(
        search,
        paginationState.activePage - 1,
        paginationState.itemsPerPage,
        `${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}`
      );
    } else {
      // setPaginationState({
      //   ...paginationState,
      //   order: 'desc',
      //   sort: 'publishedDate'
      // });
      props.getEntities(paginationState.activePage - 1, paginationState.itemsPerPage, `publishedDate,desc`);
    }
  };
```

Added the relevant interface

```
export interface IPaginationBaseState {
    itemsPerPage: number;
    sort: string;
    order: string;
    activePage: number;
}
export declare const getSortState: (location: any, itemsPerPage: any) => IPaginationBaseState;
```

The commented part is how I currently change the default sorting, however I dont think thats the best approach because the page loads 2 times.

How can I change the `useState` to initialize the sorting by `publishedDate` and `desc` order ?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working based on the question and answer in [useState object set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451029/usestate-object-set)

```
const[paginationState, setPaginationState] = useState({activePage: 1, itemsPerPage: ITEMS_PER_PAGE, sort: 'publishedDate', order: 'desc'});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jhipster 7.6.0:

just modify your .tsx as follow:

```
  const [paginationState, setPaginationState] = useState(
overridePaginationStateWithQueryParams(getSortState(props.location, ITEMS_PER_PAGE, 'publishedDate,desc'), props.location.search));
```